# After using "Import Images as Planes", texture doesn't show up

Tags: image

After importing an image as a plane, with the corresponding addon, I switch the view shading mode to texture but the object is just *white*. If I change the view to render I see the image. How can I work in texture mode and see the image?

[image: viewport shading set to texture]

[image: viewport shading set to render]

Comment: may you please post a .blend file or at least a screenshot? it kinda difficult to tell *exactly* what's going on in there. Use a service like [pasteall](http://www.pasteall.org/) or [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Comment: If you post a blend file remember to pack the image in question...

Comment: Do you have GLSL shading enabled? I don't think Multitexture handles textures properly. (If I'm right, I'll post an answer for you to accept).

Comment: GLSL messes it up, moving from render engine to render engine does not. Notice that GLSL makes it turn **black** not white.

Answer (score 1):

In the N panel under shading, select Textured Solid. This allows each object to display its texture in object mode. This is not the same as setting the view port rendered.